# SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN and SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE not working on AlertDialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have a AlertDialog in which I want the user to put in some data. The problem is that the on-screen keyboard overlaps the Dialog when it pops up. I have:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
/>
```

in my AndroidManifest.xml

and:

```java
View popupview = (LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())).inflate(R.layout.hausaufgabe_add_popup, null);

AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
alertBuilder.setTitle("Hausaufgabe Hinzufügen");
alertBuilder.setView(popupview);
//Do stuff here
AlertDialog dialog = alertBuilder.create();
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
dialog.show();
```

in my code. But it still won't work.

Here is a screenshot of what the problem looks like:

[image: Android Dialog becomes squashed when keyboard is visible]

Any advice?

Comment: Well for one thing you'd never use adjustPan | adjustResize.  You do one or the other.  They're different modes, you can't combine the two.  At best one will override the other, at worst it will put it in an undefined state.

Comment: Ok so i removed the adjust_resize and now its not crippled anymore but it doesnt move up either, so the keyboard isnt overlapping it.

Comment: same problem here ... working on android 5 but not on later versions ...